# Piwik not tracking on www

Tags: cdn, matomo

I have a website that uses CDN. The 'www' is on CDN, while the normal website http://example.com can be directly accessed from the webserver. The CDN(http://www.example.com) uses origin pull to get content from http://example.com

Now, when I access http://example.com directly, I can see entries in Piwik, however, it's not working when I access http://www.example.com. Is there something extra that I should be doing here?

1. Please note that the piwik is not hosted on the same server. I guess the server issue is not a problem, as it works when accessed directly (http://example.com)
2. I am using the technique  which doesn't reveal the Piwik Server URL. (http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/#faq_132)

Thanks.

Comment: Well why not just use a .htaccess file to direct http://www to http:// That way you won't have to worry about that

Comment: It's not the problem of www or non-www. www connects to CDN, while non-www connects to the webserver directly. The Piwik URL is on http://example.com/piwik.php (as mentioned in #2 in the question).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both **example.com** and **www.example.com** to URLs in your Websites Management on piwik side.

Answer (score 0):

Check with Firebug to see if the request is made to Piwik on your www. ?